# Android OpenGL ES Line based circle

Tags: android, opengl-es

Can someone help me with the logic of this code? It isn't drawing a circle just random lines.

```
#include <math.h>
...
void drawCircle(){
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glUseProgram(programObject);
   const float DEG2RAD = 3.14159f / 180.0f;
   int totalVertices = 360;
   const float radsPerLine = (360.f / totalVertices) * DEG2RAD;
   float lineVertices[(totalVertices * 4)];
   int i;
   int ii = 0;
   float rad = 0.8f;
   for (i = 0; i < (totalVertices); i++) {
     float degInRad = radsPerLine * i;
     float cosine = cos(degInRad);
     float sine = sin(degInRad);
     lineVertices[ii++] = 0.0f;
     lineVertices[ii++] = 0.0f;
     lineVertices[ii++] = cosine * rad;
     lineVertices[ii++] = sine * rad;
   }
   glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, lineVertices);
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
   glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, totalVertices * 4);
}
```

The fractalish pattern appears at a high number (such as 360). The other weird thing is some lines seem taller than others which is strange as well.

Comment: You are overwriting previous calculated data on each iteration. You should be incrementing i by 2.

Comment: Thanks that did help a bit but check out the update I am getting ready to write.

Comment: Your new code is still wrong, the postfix ++ operator happens after emitting a value, which means that lineVertices[ii++] = sin(degInRad)*0.8f; is overwriting previous data. change it to be ++ii.

Comment: Ahhh true dat can I use ++i in c?

Comment: Ok now we are getting somewhere but still having issues. I decided because I wanted to make it a solid circle I would add an origin point after each point. Now I am starting to get a circular object but it has a tripy almost fractal pattern to it. I will update shortly

Comment: Your buffer contains 4 components (2+2 components), but in your call to glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, lineVertices); you specify 2 componets and no stride. Depending on what do you want, you either need to specify 4 components there, or 2 and an stride of 2*sizeof(GLfloat) bytes. Check http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml

Comment: I am not sure that will help me since each point in the line is only 2 floats large (I.E. no z value). So for example GLfloat vVertices[] = { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f }; then glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices); gives me a cross.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working...

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(programObject);
const float DEG2RAD = 3.14159f / 180.0f;
int totalVertices = 360*12;
const float radsPerLine = (180.f / totalVertices) * DEG2RAD;
float lineVertices[(totalVertices * 4)];
int i;
int ii = 0;
float rad = 0.5f;
for (i = 0; i < (totalVertices); i++) {
    float degInRad = radsPerLine * i;
    float cosine = cos(degInRad);
    float sine = sin(degInRad);
    GLfloat x1 = -1 * (cosine * rad);
    GLfloat y1 = -1 * (sine * rad);
    GLfloat x2 =  (cosine * rad);
    GLfloat y2 =  (sine * rad);
    lineVertices[ii++] = x1;
    lineVertices[ii++] = y1;
    lineVertices[ii++] = x2;
    lineVertices[ii++] = y2;
}
int size = sizeof(lineVertices)/sizeof(lineVertices[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, lineVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, totalVertices * 2);
```

There are 2 main things that solved this issue...

1. I used 180 instead of 360 and just multiplied the values by -1, this allows me to use 1 line for both directions instead of 2 lines for each direction.
2. glDrawArrays expects the number of vectors not points so I had to multiply by 2 instead of 4.

Answer (score 1):

Probably is more useful to be able to specify how many segments must approximate the circle:

```
void fillWithCircleData(GLfloat *lineVertices, GLint numLines, GLfloat radius){
    const GLfloat DEG2RAD = 3.14159/180;
    const GLfloat radsPerLine = (360.f/(numLines)*DEG2RAD;
    GLint i;

    for (i=0; i < numLines; ++i)
    {
        GLfloat rads = radsPerLine*i;
        lineVertices[i*2] = cos(rads)*radius;     
        lineVertices[i*2+1] = sin(rads)*radius;
    }
}
```

Be aware that this produces `numLines` vertices, but it won't repeat the last vertex as the last vertex is the same as the first one (`2PI == 0`). This means your elements array must provide `numLines+1` indexes, being the last index the same as the first one. This saves you from processing the same vertex twice. You will need to change your primitive from `GL_LINE` to `GL_LINES_STRIP`.

**EDIT:** If you don't want to specify an elements array, just generate the last point creating an array to hold numLines+1 and change the above loop to go until `i < numLines+1`.

**Note:** Code is un-tested.